# Server response 200,but files not uploaded to server from android

Tags: php, android

I am new to android,and programming in general,I carefully followed a tutorial on how to upload a file from android device to a PHP server.I however cannot see the file uploaded on the server although the response code is 200 OK,and there is no error in logcat. I would like to use this particular code or find out exactly whats wrong with it,My code is as below.

MainActivity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {



    private static final int PICK_FILE_REQUEST = 1;
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private String selectedFilePath;
    private String SERVER_URL = "http://192.168.162.1/files/uploadToServer.php";
    ImageView ivAttachment;
    Button bUpload;
    TextView tvFileName;
    ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ivAttachment = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivAttachment);
        bUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b_upload);
        tvFileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_file_name);
        ivAttachment.setOnClickListener(this);
        bUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
        FilePath.verifyStoragePermissions(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        if(v== ivAttachment){

            //on attachment icon click
            showFileChooser();
        }
        if(v== bUpload){
            //on upload button Click
            if(selectedFilePath != null){
                dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this,"","Uploading File...",true);

                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //creating new thread to handle Http Operations
                        uploadFile(selectedFilePath);
                    }
                }).start();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Please choose a File First",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        //sets the select file to all types of files
        intent.setType("file/*");
        //allows to select data and return it
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        //starts new activity to select file and return data
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Choose File to Upload.."),PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == PICK_FILE_REQUEST){
                if(data == null){
                    //no data present
                    return;
                }


                Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
                selectedFilePath = FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
                Log.i(TAG,"Selected File Path:" + selectedFilePath);

                if(selectedFilePath != null && !selectedFilePath.equals("")){
                    tvFileName.setText(selectedFilePath);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //android upload file to server
    public int uploadFile(final String selectedFilePath){

        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        HttpURLConnection connection;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";


        int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);


        String[] parts = selectedFilePath.split("/");
        final String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];

        if (!selectedFile.isFile()){
            dialog.dismiss();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvFileName.setText("Source File Doesn't Exist: " + selectedFilePath);
                }
            });
            return 0;
        }else{
            try{
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
                URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
                connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
                connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

                //creating new dataoutputstream
                dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

                //writing bytes to data outputstream
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                        + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

                //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
                while (bytesRead > 0){
                    //write the bytes read from inputstream
                    dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                }

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

                Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
                if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                        }
                    });
                }

                //closing the input and output streams
                fileInputStream.close();
                dataOutputStream.flush();
                dataOutputStream.close();



            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"File Not Found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "URL error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cannot Read/Write File!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;
        }

    }
}
```

My PHP:

```
<?php
require "init.php";

    $file_path = "uploads/";

    $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path) ){
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

logcat:

```
09-21 15:24:59.490 10225-10264/hilz.upload W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
09-21 15:24:59.490 10225-10264/hilz.upload W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xf3ee7ec0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
09-21 15:25:00.032 10225-10566/hilz.upload I/MainActivity: Server Response is: OK: 200
```

UPDATE:

I log the response from the Server and now logcat looks like this:
D/Server Response:

```
                                                    <b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(../upload/hangouts_message.ogg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Files\UploadToServer.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
                                                    <br />
                                                    <b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php6FE8.tmp' to '../upload/hangouts_message.ogg' in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Files\UploadToServer.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />
                                                        fail
```

Comment: Result code is not important. The php script echo()s "fail" or "success". Now what are you receiving?

Comment: wherewould i check that?? am amatuer,and it appears code just checks for response from server

Comment: Indeed. Your code at the moment is not reading the echos. So you are blind. You dont know what happens. Now you are writing data to the output stream of the connection. That is ok to send data. To read the echos you should read from the input stream of the connection.

Comment: could you help me wth how exactly i can make that happen given current code?

Comment: Of course. You only have to add a few lines. Like where you read from the file input stream. Google for read input stream to string.

Comment: Thanks managed to get exact error from server,i tried to upload ringtone from device to server, i get this error " <b>Warning</b>:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/hangouts_message.ogg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Files\UploadToServer.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />" it looks like looking for fie to upload in place where it should upload to,any suggestions?

Comment: `it looks like looking for fie to upload in place where it should upload to`. Sorry i do not understand a word of this. Please rephrase.

Comment: i get the error in " " in my comment,ignore the last sentence thats just me guessing what could be wrong

Comment: `i get the error in " " in my comment`. ???? Such answers are not very helpfull. Dont understand a word of this either.

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: The message is clear: "no such file or directory".  What do you think it is for you in this case? A directory or a file that is missing?

Comment: i dont know which it is,the android part shows no error,so am guessing its got to do with the server,is the php script supposed to create the file in htdocs which it says is missing?

Comment: I think the file isnt uploaded because when i check the "C:\xampp\tmp" path the file isnt there,and dont know why its not uploading

Comment: The file is uploaded. It is put by php in a temp directory on the server already. The problem starts only if you try to move the file. But you did not answer a simple question: what is missing here? A file or a directory. I agree that the php message is unclear indeed.

Comment: the "uploads" folder and file both missing i guess

Comment: `i check the "C:\xampp\tmp" `. Ok. But for which file name were you looking? Php will give a temp file an unrecognizable name.

Comment: Unable to move 'C:\xampp\tmp\php2456.tmp' so i was looking for php2456.tmp

Comment: Indeed the 'uploads' folder is missing. And your temp file can not be moved to a non existent directory. You now know what you have to do. You have two options.

Comment: Wow thank you so much,works!! I thought the folder is automatically added by PHP,Thank you again